# Icarus Verilog: Multibit array parse error

Tags: verilog, hdl, icarus

What is the proper multibit array declaration in Icarus Verilog? I'm getting a parse error in this code 
`input [19:0] array [0:9];` but when I tried `input [20*10-1] array;`, there's no parse error but there are errors in my input/output.

Comment: I see. The way I handle my array is through the index of the unpacked array that's why I'm getting errors. But why is `input [19:0] array [0:9];` illegal in Icarus Verilog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verilog, not just Icarus, does not allow declaring IOs as multidimensional arrays. It just doesn't. SystemVerilog does. People doing different things for working this problem around, like declaring multidimensional wires, and then connecting them to the flat-defined input.